# Will replacing the default player skin interfere with my premium profile skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made a custom skin. If I want to go and change the original Steve texture in the game files, would it mess up my skin I have made and uploaded to my Minecraft profile? My friend wants to try something involving replacing the default Steve skin and I don't want him to mess up my custom skin in the process.

Comment: You might need to elaborate. Are you changing the original, default skin, or a re you creating a different custom skin that looks like the original, with a few changes?

Comment: And if you are altering the original skin, what changes are you making?

Comment: he made a custom skin for the default that is totally different, and wants me  to see what happens if I replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way:

The default skin, the Steve skin, is like a sock pulled over the frame of the Player Model. Then any custom skin you apply, is like another sock over the top of that.

If you change the Steve skin, because you still have a custom skin over the top, you'll still just see the custom skin (the sock on the outside).

The only thing that might affect your custom skin, is if you add a "helmet" to the Steve skin. To explain: on some skins, players have added things like a hood or headphones, that sit on another layer. If this is applied to the Steve Skin, that *will* show up on your custom skin.

*However*, I don't believe it is actually possible to do that.

Comment: I don't believe this is true. I'm pretty sure that if the player has a custom skin, the Steve skin will not apply at all, even if it has an outer layer.

Comment: PangeaCake is correct: it's not like a sock over a sock, it's like... uh... you've got a custom sock, but if you forget it at home, or you play with a friend who doesn't have their own sock, the butler waiting outside the Minecraft Mansion who hates bare feet will force anyone missing a sock to wear the standard sock before letting you or them past, but will leave anyone already wearing a sock completely alone.

Comment: I like the way the "sock" analogy is taking off...

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [Maybe we are underestimating the sneakiness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lYBVi3ALWA)